# Why RequestMapping in Spring gets null value

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

When i submit form it processes and goes to controller class. but in RequestMapping i am not getting the value. When i submit form it processes and goes to controller class. but in RequestMapping i am not getting the value. 
When i submit form it processes and goes to controller class. but in RequestMapping i am not getting the value.

**index.jsp**

```
<form method="POSt" action="login.htm">
            Email : <input type="text" path="txtemail"/>
            Password : <input type="text" path="txtpwd"/><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
           </form>
```

**controller.java**

```
@Controller
public class controller extends model{
@RequestMapping(value="/login",method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String login(HttpServletRequest request, 
        @RequestParam(value="txtemail", required=false)String email,
        @RequestParam(value="txtpwd", required=false) String password){

     controller_save obj=new controller_save();
     obj.setEmail(email);
     obj.setPassword(password);   
     return "index";
 }   
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: an `input` element doesn't have a `path` property. Your element will get a random id/name and doesn't match the `@RequestParam` hence it will always be `null`.

Comment: @M.Deinum not works .. tried .. remember it is Spring. not simple jsp.

Comment: Trust me I know, I wrote the book... What did you try? Your input element needs a name not a path.

Comment: Lotsssssssssss of thanksss bro @M.Deinum :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace this:

```
 <form method="POSt" action="login.htm">
```

To:

```
  <form method="POST" action="/login">
```

With using `login` instead of `login.htm` because you have `value="/login"`:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/login",method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

And write these lines like this:

```
   Email : <input type="text" name="txtemail" path="txtemail"/>
   Password : <input type="text" name="txtpwd" path="txtpwd"/><br>
```

And:

```
  @RequestParam(value="txtemail", required=false) String txtemail,
  @RequestParam(value="txtpwd", required=false) String txtpwd){
```

Comment: By default `/login` will also introduce a mapping for `/login.*` (unless it is switched off manually, but I highly doubt that).

Comment: bro ,, i have debugged my code. it comes to controller.java. but gets null value in     `obj.setEmail(email)`

Answer (score 0):

Use login instead of login.htm or /login in form 
`<form method="POST" action="login">`